# How to get RubyMine to handle scopes correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubymine

RubyMine provides auto-completion and error/warning inspections for your code, and a lot of the time it works great, but for some reason as soon as I use a scope on one of my Rails models, all the sudden RubyMine doesn't know what the type of the result coming from the scope is.

Even simple scopes break the inspections, e.g.:

`scope :all1, all()`

`scope :all2, all()`

Is there a way to fix this? Is this a known issue in RubyMine (I'm using 5.4)?

Comment: This actually seems to be a more general problem with RubyMine being unable to identify symbols that will only be present at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This actually seems to be a more general problem with RubyMine being unable to identify symbols that will only be present at runtime. So, we may have to just wait for a new version of RubyMine.